# Taking parts of a sentence in String using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this sentences which I want to manipulate and take its information:

> Hello. Yr data allocation based on Fair Usage
>   Policy is **10,240.0MB**. Yr current usage is **2,858.6MB**. Balance:
>   **7,381.4MB**. Your plan will be renewed on: **00:00:00 28-08-2014**.

I would like to only take the bold part. I've been thinking on using Regex to manipulate this, but I haven't figured out a way to do it because of the complex structure.

Can anyone guide me? I'm using Java to do this.

Comment: Are there any values similar to bold ones which you don't want to match?

Comment: Regex should be used when you have *similar* pattern in the String. **10,240.0MB** and **00:00:00 28-08-2014.** don't exactly form a pattern.

Comment: If the only dynamic parts of this sentence are the bold parts it might make more sense to use a substring + regex as you know the preceeding character lengths. Remove x characters. Regex match everything until "MB" repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match parts similar to `10,240.0MB` you can use

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*[.]\d[KMGT]B\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ay10TsLujURdc__i) or [Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aM7dI4/1)

To match parts like `00:00:00 28-08-2014` you can use

```
\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yBx7YoLgICJH7CFx) or [Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC9pG4/1)

If you want to combine these two regexes simply use OR operator `|`. Also you will have to escape `\` in String to create such literal. So in Java you will need to write it as

```
String regex = "\\b\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*[.]\\d[KMGT]B\\b"
        + "|\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} \\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\\b";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely certain that the String will always be similar to this, you can use this regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hello. Yr data allocation based on Fair Usage Policy is 10,240.0MB. Yr current usage is 2,858.6MB. Balance: 7,381.4MB. Your plan will be renewed on: 00:00:00 28-08-2014.";
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("(\\d+.*?MB)|(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\\.)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
10,240.0MB
2,858.6MB
7,381.4MB
00:00:00 28-08-2014.
```